# Linker error with simple threaded program (symbols from boost_chrono missing)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

I'm learning boost::timed_mutex

The follwing code cannot be compiled:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void wait(int seconds)
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
}

boost::timed_mutex mutex;

void thread1()
{
  using boost::this_thread::get_id;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    wait(1);
    boost::unique_lock<boost::timed_mutex> lock{mutex};
    std::cout << "Thread " << get_id() << ": " << i << std::endl;
    boost::timed_mutex *m = lock.release();
    m->unlock();
  }
}

void thread2()
{
  using boost::this_thread::get_id;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    wait(1);
    boost::unique_lock<boost::timed_mutex> lock{mutex,
      boost::try_to_lock};
    if (lock.owns_lock() || lock.try_lock_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1}))
    {
      std::cout << "Thread " << get_id() << ": " << i << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  boost::thread t1{thread1};
  boost::thread t2{thread2};
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

My compile command is:

g++ -std=c++11 unique_lock.cpp -o unique_lock -g -lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt -pthread -lboost_timer

The error is something like the following:

```
/bin/ld: /tmp/ccRVKHNh.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6chrono12system_clock3nowEv'
/usr/lib64/libboost_chrono.so.1.53.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Error is: /bin/ld: /tmp/ccRVKHNh.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6chrono12system_clock3nowEv'
/usr/lib64/libboost_chrono.so.1.53.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you try to add `-lboost_chrono` ?

Comment: I forgot -lboost_chrono, it now works~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently -lboost_chrono is missing.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d858cdf81fe562fb)